# Creating a Box Matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I am relatively new to python and I am struggling to work this out. Its pretty simple but I am horrible at coding.

Write a function box_matrix(rows, cols) which creates a new matrix (a 2D NumPy array) with the given number of rows and columns, such that all elements are 0, except for the rows and columns at the "edges" of the matrix, which should be 1, (a "hollow" or "box" matrix").

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should post what you have done so fa. Code? Pseudocode?

Answer (score 1):

Start with a matrix of 0's, as indexing in python starts at 0 your final rows and columns are rows - 1 and cols - 1. The : in the indexing means all rows or all columns. Use these two indexing facts to fill in the "box" positions with 1.

```
import numpy as np

def box_matrix(rows,cols):
    mat = np.zeros( (rows,cols ))
    mat[:,0] = 1
    mat[0,:] = 1
    mat[rows-1,:] = 1
    mat[:,cols-1] = 1
    return mat

bm = box_matrix(4,4)

print bm
```